# Clear Merged Cell Contents Based on Data Validation List Selection

Tags: excel, vba, validation, merge

I'm trying to clear the contents of a merged cell based on the selection from a data validation list (the list is also in merged cells). And yes, "Don't use merged cells!" is great advice (I prefer "center across") but would complicate things in this case. I've tried naming the merged cells, using "MergeArea," etc. but I haven't been successful in finding a solution yet.

Below is the latest iteration I have. Please note I've been trying to make just one selection ("Yes." in this case) work before adding in the second selection (or "blank" in this case).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Range("Max_Advance").MergeArea Then
    If Range.Validation.Type = 2 Then
        Range("Days_Needed").MergeArea.ClearContents
    End If
End If
exitHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Can anyone help? I've also attached a picture to visually show what I'm working with:

[image: Clear Contents Example]

Comment: `If Range.Validation.Type = 2 Then`, you need to specify what range you're checking there. I assume you get an error(s) with this code? What error, where?

Comment: I wasn't getting errors (or didn't know how to look for them). When I clicked the "run macro" button it would ask for the macro name. Since this was a private sub, maybe it wasn't showing up? Is there a way to debug private subs? Sorry, new to this. The response sktneer provided worked.

Comment: Ah - Private subs aren't able to be called via the "View Macros" window.  The `Private` means they're hidden from that view.  On top of that, AFAIK the only way to trigger a `Worksheet_Change()` sub is to actually make a change/click in-out of a cell.  If you wanted to test a `Private` sub, you can type the sub's name into the Immediate Window (press CTRL+G to show this in the VBEditor).  I.e. `Private Sub myMacro()` can be called just by typing `myMacro` in the Immediate Window and hit ENTER.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for that explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address(0, 0) = "A2" Then
    On Error GoTo exitHandler
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If LCase(Target.Value) <> "no. please enter." Then
        Range("Days_Needed").MergeArea.ClearContents
    End If
End If
exitHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can usually clear the contents of a merged cell by treating it as if it was the first cell in the merge.

for example:

```
Range("A2")=""
```